# iOS Swift: Properly Initializing a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitableview

For the sake of learning the ropes with respect to iOS development; I am trying to create a tableview with various Facebook-like "Posts". For this question i will refer to a "Photo Post" who's XIB can be seen below:

**PhotoPostTableViewCell.xib:**

[image]

```
class PhotoPostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var postingUserImageButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var postingUserNameButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeStampLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var primaryImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postContentsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rippleLikesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rippleButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    ...
}
```

This post is **required** to have the following:

`postingUserID` of type `Int` to reference to a custom User class to link up the User image and user name(top left corner)

`photo` of type `UIImage` to hold the primary image for the post

`postTimeStamp` of type `String` to capture the time the post was posted

`rippleLikes` of type `Int` to hold the number of "likes" the post has; this will be initialized to `0`

`postID` of type `Int` so that this post can be referenced elsewhere

This post also has an **optional** `String` named `postContentLabel`

I have tried various different approaches, but seem to always end up with an error so I thought i would seek some advice.

**My question is as follows:**

What is the most professional/efficient way to define this class and create/initialize this table view cell class from within the respective tableview delegate method

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to have a property that stores the entity the cell is representing.

```
class PhotoPostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var postContentLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var postPhotoImageView: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet weak var postTimestampLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var rippleLikesLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel?

    // MARK: Properties

    var photoPost: PhotoPost? {
        didSet {
            // configure your outlets here
            // e.g. postContentLabel.text = photoPost?.content
        }
    }
}
```

You can move the outlet configuration code from the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to the cell itself and just set the `photoPost` property of the cell.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PhotoPostTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PhotoPostCell")
}

...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhotoPostCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoPostTableViewCell

    cell.photoPost = photoPosts[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Your photo post class could look like this:

```
class PhotoPost {

    // MARK: Properties

    var contents: String?
    var id: Int!
    var photo: UIImage!
    var rippleLikes: Int!
    var timestamp: Double!
    var userID: Int!

    init(json: [String: Any]) {

        self.contents = json["contents"] as? String
        self.id = json["id"] as? Int
        self.photo = ...
        self.rippleLikes = json["rippleLikes"] as? Int
        self.timestamp = json["timestamp"] as? Double
        self.userID = json["userID"] as? Int
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you go into more detail about the best way of defining a required variable that has no association with the XIB? i.e. PostID

Comment: Well as I've explained above, I do suggest creating a class to represent your post as it's a good way to spread out code for maintainability and reusability. You can define the required and optional variables here.

Comment: I've updated my answer by adding an example of what `PhotoPost` could look like. You can use an optional String to define the optional post contents meaning `post.contents` can be nil. Technically, so can all it's other properties however they are force unwrapped so you will need to use an if statement to check if they are nil.